# Width cut off on mobile, works resizing desktop browser

Tags: css, mobile, width, viewport

I am developing a website with a desktop and iPhone 4 viewport. When I am doing the bulk of development and viewing it through my desktop's browser using a viewport chrome extension, it is rendered fine and looks good. But when I view it on my iPhone 4s the width is corrupted. I have no logic that tells it to act like this. I cannot see what the issue is, was wondering if anyone could think of some possible problems?

> Desktop (at 320 viewport): -----

[image]

> iPhone 4S:

[image]

Query used for the  .container{}  class that wraps the entire site.

```
.container {
 text-align: center;

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
@media (min-width : 320px) {
    .container {
        width:75%;
    }
}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have two problems at work here that are unrelated to your `.container`. Why do I think this? Your menu is showing up nice and large but your other content isn't. You said .container wraps *everything*. So we shouldn't be seeing a discrepancy there.

So, you're two problems are likely related to:

1. You're probably missing some meta tags in your `<head>`. It looks like media queries seem to be working for you, but your scale is off. Try adding in `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
2. Your menu styles. Do they have a set size? Is there a media query that's adjusting it?

Without seeing the menu styles, I can't really say what exactly is wrong there...

Answer (score 0):

use this code for iphone 4

Screent width Between 320px to 480px

```
.container {
 text-align: center;

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
@media and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
    .container {
        width:75%;
    }
}
```

Else use below code for <320px widht screen

```
.container {
 text-align: center;

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
@media (max-width : 320px) {
    .container {
        width:75%;
    }
}
```

And your mistake is, You wrongly put `min-width : 320px` instead of `max-width : 320px`

[More...](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it's something to do with the Retina display. The viewport on your desktop measures pixels on an ordinary display. On a 4s 320 pixels are not actually full screen - instead it's 640. You should check out the device pixel ration query http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/